# How to run scala specs 2 in eclipse

Tags: scala, scala-ide, specs2

How to run `scala`  `specs 2` in `eclipse` (scala-ide)?

My steps were:

> 1. sbt eclipse - generate eclipse project from existing source
> 2. eclise: import project - open project in eclipse ide
> 3. Put break-point in my SPECS 2 test (class MyTest extends Specification  { ... )
> 4. Try to run test ...**?** (usually I do it in IntelliJ IDEA.. but today going to check how eclipse works with debug in `scala`..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, you can use a little hack. If you annotate your Specs2 class as follows:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

With older versions of specs2, this should be:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitSuiteRunner])
```

The Scala IDE can run it with the JUnit runner simply through the popup menu (see the details [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/testingframeworks/index.html)).

I'm working on a Specs2 plug-in for the Scala IDE (well, unfortunately I haven't really found time for it for a while, but it's still on my list).

It has a working version for the previous version of the Scala IDE, it is a bit difficult to set it up but works. See the details here: http://rlegendi.github.io/specs2-runner/

Comment: It seems to be @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) now

Comment: Is there anyway to declare a super-trait with the @RunWith annotation so you don't have to put the annotation at the top of all your classes?

Comment: IIRC there was an issue with that and I wasn't able to go that road (but that was 2 years ago).

Comment: FWIW scala-ide.org has a good run down: http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/testingframeworks/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure the `build.sbt` file included the following information:

```
scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.5" % "test",
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % "3.6.5" % "test",
```